# Print bash variable without last newline

Tags: string, bash, printf

I use this bash code to copy files content

```
#!/bin/bash

readarray content < ./test
printf "%s" "${content[@]}"
```

The problem is that I get what I want but with *additional* newline at the end. How can I get rid of that newline?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *problem* is created by `readarray` (/`mapfile`), which adds a trailing newline to each array element (line), you need to tell it to not do so by using the `-t` option.

```
readarray -t content < ./test
```

---

If you must deal with it using `printf`, use parameter expansion to get rid of trailing newlines from array elements:

```
printf '%s' "${foo[@]/$'\n'/}"
```

**Example:**

```
$ readarray foo <<<$'foobar\n\nspamegg'
$ printf '%s' "${foo[@]}"
foobar

spamegg
$ printf '%s' "${foo[@]/$'\n'/}"
foobarspamegg
```

---

If you want to get rid of the trailing newline only from the last element of the array, you need to do it in two steps. At first print all array elements except the last one, and finally print the last element with the trailing newline removed:

```
printf '%s' "${content[@]:0:$((${#content[@]}-1))}"; printf '%s' "${content[${#content[@]}-1]/$'\n'/}"
```

**Example:**

```
$ printf '%s' "${foo[@]:0:$((${#foo[@]}-1))}"; printf '%s' "${foo[${#foo[@]}-1]/$'\n'/}"
foobar

spamegg
```

Comment: Yes, I know the `-t` option. However, my file contains some newlines and some empty-lines, and I want them in my output. `-t` removes removes newlines that I want.

Comment: Thanks, but that is still not what I want. In your example I *want* `\n\n` to be printed. I just want to remove one final newline.

Comment: Great! Now it seems so simple.